# How to use this multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am getting a multidimensional array in form of JSON from a php file as AJAX response , there are two values I am getting from it , name and email , I need to update name and email of two respective divs each 5 seconds.

PHP response in JSON form:  {"sophia":"email@domain.com"}

Below is my javascript code:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                for (var index in links) {
              //update name div
               document.getElementById("name").innerHTML= links[index]; 
             //update email div
               document.getElementById("email").innerHTML= links[index];
                  }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_data.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }, 5000);
```

My html code:

```
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="email"></div>
```

Comment: Should it not be `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML= index;`?

Comment: So, whats the problem? You said your background, your goal, your attempt... what's wrong?

Comment: `JSON` === `J`ava`S`cript `O`bject `N`otation. What you have is a JS object, not an array. `links.sophia` will get you the email, if you don't know what the properties will be, `for (var p in links) { if (links.hasOwnProperty(p)) links[p];` is how you _should_ iterate over a JS object

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks, now I realized it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your Object looks like `{"sophia":"email@domain.com"};` Change it to:

```
....
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML= index;   //sophia
         //update email div
document.getElementById("email").innerHTML= links[index];  //obj['sophia']= email@domain.com
....
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/r0hry8x0/